# Sending commands to stm32 board

Tags: command, usb, port, stm32

I'm trying to send commands to an STM32F4 microcontroller board via terminal in Linux.

I've tried the following commands:

```
~$: stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw           

~$: echo -e -n "\xAA\0xAB\0x10\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x01\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00" > dev/ttyACM0   (this command should tell the stm32 to start recording)
```

And there is no error, but my STM32F4 board isn't giving me any response back.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is your board ?

Comment: The board is STM32F4 discovery board.

Comment: I have a stm32f429 discovery and there is no ttyACMx port for it. you seem to have a different model.

Comment: Are you using it on Linux also? Anyway, I got the correct answer. You have to in super user mode (command is: sudo su) and then enter the command shown in the question.

Comment: Have you configured the baudrate of the serial-port

(/dev/ttyACM0 is the serial-port name on some systems, like the raspberry PI, for those who do not know)